# Multiples VUEX en VUEJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

buen día.
Tengo un problema actualmente con vuejs y vuex.
Una persona desarrollo o implemento vuex en el proyecto y sirve solo para guardar el token de la app, pero para intentar agregar nuevos módulos tengo problemas con el getter.

> El siguiente es el código original   **store/index.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import decode from 'jwt-decode';
import router from '@/router';
import { Socket } from 'socket.io-client';

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    token: null,
    user: null,
    count: 0,
    io: {}
  },
  mutations: {
    setToken(state, token) {
      state.token = token;

    },
    setUser(state, user) {
      state.user = user;
    },
    SOCKET_COUNTER_INCREMENT (state, counter) {
      state.count = counter;
    },
    SOCKET_COUNTER_DECREMENT (state, counter) {
      state.count = counter;
    },
    setSocket: (state, socket) => {
      state.io = socket;
      console.log("frontend socket is connected");
    }
  },
  actions: {
    saveToken({ commit }, token) {
      commit("setToken", token);
      commit("setUser", decode(token));
      localStorage.setItem("token", token);
    },
    autologin({ commit }) {
      let token = localStorage.getItem("token");
      if (token) {
        commit("setToken", token);
        commit("setUser", decode(token));
      }
      router.push({ name: 'Home' });
    },
    outUser({ commit }) {
      commit("setToken", null);
      commit("setUser", null);
      localStorage.removeItem("token");
      router.push({ name: 'login' });
    },
    socket_increment: ({state, rootState}) => {
      rootState.io.emit('increment', state.count)
    },
    socket_decrement: ({state, rootState}) => {
      rootState.io.emit('decrement', state.count)
    }

  },
  getters: {
    count (state) {
      return state.count;
    }
  },
  modules: {
    
  }
})
```

> **main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';
import store from './store';
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify';
import axios from 'axios';
import VueSocketIO from 'vue-socket.io';


Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.use(new VueSocketIO({
  debug: true,
  connection: 'http://localhost:3000',
  vuex: {
    store,
    actionPrefix: 'SOCKET_',
    mutationPrefix: 'SOCKET_'
  }
}));
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000/api';

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  beforeCreate () {
    store.commit('setSocket', this.$socket);
  },
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Esto se hace uso en el dashboard para permisos.

```
computed: {
    isLogged() {
      return this.$store.state.user;
    },
    checkAdmin() {
      return this.$store.state.user && this.$store.state.user.user_rol == 'admin__';
    },
    checkTech() {
      return this.$store.state.user && this.$store.state.user.user_rol == 'tech__';
    },
    checkCustomer() {
      return this.$store.state.user && this.$store.state.user.user_rol == 'customer';
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.$store.dispatch("autologin");
  },
```

**Eso funciona correctamente, bueno lo que debe de funcionar.**

En mi implementación tengo:

> **store/index.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import moduleUserStorage from './modules/userStore'
import moduleTokenStore  from './modules/tokenStore';

Vue.use(Vuex)
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    moduleUserStorage,
    moduleTokenStore
  }
})
```

> **store/modules/tojenStore.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import decode from 'jwt-decode';
import router from '@/router';
Vue.use(Vuex)
export const moduleTokenStore = new Vuex.Store({
  namespaced: true, // Add this here
  state: {
    token: null,
    user: null,
    count: 0,
    io: {}
  },
  mutations: {
    setToken(state, token) {
      state.token = token;

    },
    setUser(state, user) {
      state.user = user;
    },
    SOCKET_COUNTER_INCREMENT (state, counter) {
      state.count = counter;
    },
    SOCKET_COUNTER_DECREMENT (state, counter) {
      state.count = counter;
    },
    setSocket: (state, socket) => {
      state.io = socket;
      console.log("frontend socket is connected");
    }
  },
  actions: {
    saveToken({ commit }, token) {
      commit("setToken", token);
      commit("setUser", decode(token));
      localStorage.setItem("token", token);
    },
    autologin({ commit }) {
      let token = localStorage.getItem("token");
      if (token) {
        commit("setToken", token);
        commit("setUser", decode(token));
      }
      router.push({ name: 'Home' });
    },
    outUser({ commit }) {
      commit("setToken", null);
      commit("setUser", null);
      localStorage.removeItem("token");
      router.push({ name: 'login' });
    },
    socket_increment: ({state, rootState}) => {
      rootState.io.emit('increment', state.count)
    },
    socket_decrement: ({state, rootState}) => {
      rootState.io.emit('decrement', state.count)
    }

  },
  getters: {
    count (state) {
      return state.count;
    }
  },
  modules: {

  }
});
```

> **store/modules/userStore.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
Vue.use(Vuex)
export const moduleUserStorage = new Vuex.Store({
  namespaced: true, // Add this here
  state: {
    userStorage: null
  },
  mutations: {
    setUser(state, user) {
      state.userStorage.push(user)
    }
  },
  actions: {
    saveUser({commit}, user) {
      if (!user)
        return
      commit('setUser', user);
    }
  },
  modules: {
    
  }
});
```

El main.js se quedo igual sin embargo al crear esa estructura, me marca un error en consola y se cuelga la aplicación.

[image: Error console, vuex, vue]

[image: error npm route import's]

MUCHAS GRACIAS, por su atención y espero puedan apoyarme con la solución.
Saludos

Comment: en principio en store/modules/userStore.js no tienes definida la seccion de getters de ahi el error de que no encuentra la propiedad, por otro lado, para tener un poco mas limpio tu codigo en los componentes podrias usar mapGetters y mapActions de Vuex para que se vea mejor el codigo.

Comment: Muy bien, voy a checar eso. 
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrias usar el Store para llamar a multiples, por ejemplo yo lo tengo configurado asi:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

// importas los getters, mutations, actions y state
import state from "./state"
import getters from "./getters"
import mutations from "./mutations"
import actions from "./actions"

Vue.use(Vuex)

creas las constantes
// import moduleTodo from './todo/moduleTodo.js'
import moduleCalendar from './calendar/moduleCalendar.js'
import moduleChat from './chat/moduleChat.js'
// import moduleEmail from './email/moduleEmail.js'
import moduleAuth from './auth/moduleAuth.js'
import moduleUser from './user-management/moduleUserManagement.js'
import moduleECommerce from './eCommerce/moduleECommerce.js'


export default new Vuex.Store({
    getters,
    mutations,
    state,
    actions,
    modules: {
        // todo: moduleTodo,
        calendar: moduleCalendar,
        chat: moduleChat,
        // email: moduleEmail,
        auth: moduleAuth,
        user: moduleUser,
        eCommerce: moduleECommerce,
    },
    strict: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
})
```

Yo en lo personal prefiero tener mutations, actions, getters y state por separado para cada modulo, asi mantengo organizado mi codigo

una vez defines los modulos en el archivo store/index.js puedes crearte una nueva carpeta para los nuevos states, pero recuerda crear el archivo que tendra la logic,

si notas en moduleUser yo llamo al directorio user-management y despues al archivo moduleUserManagement.js que esta dentro de user-management, este archivo tiene la logica, te dejo un ejemplo aqui debajo:

```
//IMPORTEE LO QUE DESEO MANTENER POR SEPARADO, SI A TI SOLO TE INTERESA EL STATE PUEDES QUITAR EL RESTO
import state from './moduleUserManagementState.js'
import mutations from './moduleUserManagementMutations.js'
import actions from './moduleUserManagementActions.js'
import getters from './moduleUserManagementGetters.js'

export default {
  isRegistered: false,
  namespaced: true,
  state: state,
  mutations: mutations,
  actions: actions,
  getters: getters
}
```

Y por ultimo ya crear el archivo que contendra los states, en mi caso es moduleUserManagementState.js

```
export default {

  role: [],
}
```

Espero haber sido claro y espero que te ayude de algo!, saludos!